# How to find and replace regex in Xcode

Tags: regex, xcode

I want to add "=" before number 3 and ";" after 3 below line

before:

```
static NSInteger const  LOAD_USER_PAGE 3
...
...
```

after:

```
 static NSInteger const  LOAD_USER_PAGE = 3;
```

There are lots of lines like this.

How could I do this in XCode?

Answer (score 2):

Press Magnifier icon next to find text area.
Select Edit Find Options-> Regex

Then,

Find Text Box

([0-9].$)

Replace Text Box:

= $1;